# Serial Communication c# terminal, changing the stop bits ruins the comunication

Tags: c#, serial-communication

so I wrote a terminal in c# and I need to communicate with a **kl25z microprocessor**.

the application needs to support the option to choose the number of stop bits, the baud rate and the parity method.

I managed to sort it out with the baud rate but when I try to change the stop bits something goes out of sync and I cant figure out what.
the problem is that the uart is getting jibrish kind of chars instead of what I intended it to get, it does work well when I use one stop bit so I assume I just missed something in my code

I'll add the part of the code that gives me hard time:
this is only the c# part, my terminal I'm pretty sure that the problem is here 
and not in the kl25z code

```
public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent(); //init all variables
    getAvailablePorts(); //fill the ports combo box with all the ports
}

void getAvailablePorts() {
    String[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames(); //get the names of all availoable ports
    comboBox1.Items.AddRange(ports); //add all the ports names to the combo box
}

private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) {
    try {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort) sender;
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen & sp.IsOpen) {
            string indata = sp.ReadLine();

            Invoke(new Action(() => textBox1.Text = indata));

            if (indata.Equals("new settings been set") || 
                indata.Equals("\0new settings been set") ||
                indata.Equals("new settings been set??")) {

                // baud rate
                Invoke(new Action(() => baud = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox3.Text)));
                Invoke(new Action(() => serialPort1.BaudRate = baud));
    //end bits                       
                Invoke(new Action(() => serialPort1.StopBits = end));
            }
        }
    } catch (System.IO.IOException error) {
        return;
    } catch (System.InvalidOperationException error) {
        return;
    }
}

//here i open the port
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { //start port
    try { // give the micro processor the info it needs about the settings 
        serialPort1.Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSendXOnXOff;
        serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
        serialPort1.PortName = comboBox1.Text; //port
        serialPort1.BaudRate = baud; //baud rate current
        //  serialPort1.Parity= parity;//parity current
        serialPort1.StopBits = end; //stopBits  current 
        serialPort1.DataBits = bits; //current

        //sort strings to send
        String baudString = comboBox3.Text;
        String StopString = comboBox6.Text;
        String bitsString = comboBox2.Text;
        String parityString = comboBox4.Text;
        String startString = comboBox5.Text;
        serialPort1.Open(); //open port
        bitsString = "8";

        //send properties to klz
        serialPort1.Write("prop" + "$" + baudString + "$" + StopString + "$" + bitsString + "$" + parityString + "$" + startString + "$"); 

        if (Convert.ToInt32(comboBox6.Text) == 1) {
            end = StopBits.One;
        } else {
            end = StopBits.Two;
        }

        bits = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox2.Text);
    } catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) {
        textBox1.Text = "Unauthorized Access";
    }

    try {
        progressBar1.Value = 100;
        button1.Enabled = true;
        button2.Enabled = true;
        button3.Enabled = false;
        button4.Enabled = true;
        textBox2.Enabled = true;
    } catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) {
        textBox1.Text = "Unauthorized Access";
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, C is becoming stranger every day.... No for real, is there any reason this is tagged C?

Comment: sorry about that i assumed i should add this tag because of my microcontroller part, edited it now

Comment: *"my microcontroller part"* - the desync part may be related to it. I would rather close and open port (reconnecting) when such a big change (as stop bits) has to be made. Maybe you can add a special command, which you send before changing stopbits, so that mc stops communicating and provide a way to re-establish communications.

Comment: It is not a random number, the transmitter and receiver must agree on the number of stop bits.  If there is a mismatch then the receiver detects a framing error and might substitute the received byte with an error character.  You might discover that you, say, need 2 in the transmitter and 1 in the receiver if the baudrate clocks are out of whack too much.  They never agree completely.  You then have to lower the baudrate.  Using Invoke() in the DataReceived event is a bad practice, it easily deadlocks the Close() method.

Comment: thanks  what do you suggest i do instead of using invoke?  and just to make sure i understand, you say that if i change the stop bits i may need to change the baud rate as well for a good sync ?

Comment: I really don't understand what you're asking. The essence of your question seems to be "I used the wrong configuration for the serial port, and get the wrong data".  Not only is there not a _question_ there, the behavior seems completely expected. Why would you expect to get correct data even when you're using the wrong configuration?

Comment: Why am i usibg the wrong condiguration? I change the stop bits on my microcontroller and the stop bits on my pc side